# Checkbox in Recycler View item when checked to true is immedietaly checked to false

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-adapter, rx-java2

I am using RxJava2, Kotlin and Room for my example.

Here is the adapter for populating my items to the recyclerView:

```
class ShoppingListDetailsAdapter(val list: ArrayList<ShoppingListElementItem>, val context: Context, val listener: ShoppingItemCheckboxListener, val isArchived: Boolean) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppingListDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.count()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_shopping_list_element, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    val item = list.get(position)
    holder?.name?.setText(item.name)
    if(item.isCompleted){
        holder?.isCompleted?.isChecked = true
    }


    if(isArchived)
    holder?.isCompleted?.isEnabled = false
    else{
        holder?.isCompleted?.isEnabled = true
    }

    holder?.isCompleted?.setOnCheckedChangeListener{
        buttonView, isChecked ->
        item.isCompleted = isChecked
        listener.onClick(position, isChecked)
    }


}


inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var name: TextView
    var isCompleted: CheckBox
    private var viewClickListener: ShoppingItemCheckboxListener? = null


    init {
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.itemName)
        isCompleted = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)
    }


}

fun removeItem(position: Int) {
    list.removeAt(position)
    // notify the item removed by position
    // to perform recycler view delete animations
    // NOTE: don't call notifyDataSetChanged()
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}

fun restoreItem(item: ShoppingListElementItem, position: Int) {
    list.add(position, item)
    // notify item added by position
    notifyItemInserted(position)
   }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
class ShoppingListViewModel(private val dataSource: ShoppingListDao) : ViewModel() {

fun createShoppingList(listName: String){
    val arrayList = ArrayList<ShoppingListItem>()
    val shoppingList = ShoppingList(name = listName, isArchived = false, items = arrayList, timestamp = Date())
    dataSource.insertShoppingList(shoppingList)
}

fun createShoppingListItem(itemName: String, shoppingListId: Int){
    dataSource.getShoppingList(shoppingListId)
            .firstElement()
            .subscribe {
                shoppingList: ShoppingList ->
                val items = shoppingList.items
                 items.add(ShoppingListItem(itemName, false, Date()))

                dataSource.updateShoppingList(shoppingList = shoppingList)
            }
}

fun getShoppingLists(): Flowable<List<ShoppingList>> {
    return dataSource.getActiveShoppingLists()
            .map {
                t -> t.sortedByDescending { it.timestamp }
            }
}

fun getArchivedLists(): Flowable<List<ShoppingList>> {
    return dataSource.getArchivedShoppingLists()
            .map {
                t -> t.sortedByDescending { it.timestamp }
            }

}

fun getShoppingList(id: Int): Flowable<ShoppingList> {
    return dataSource.getShoppingList(id)
}

fun archiveItem(deletedShoppingListItem: com.app.shoppinglistapp.ui.ShoppingListDTO) {

   dataSource.archiveShoppingList(deletedShoppingListItem.id)
}

fun reArchiveItem(deletedShoppingListItem: com.app.shoppinglistapp.ui.ShoppingListDTO){

    dataSource.reArchiveShoppingList(deletedShoppingListItem.id)
}

fun removeShoppingListItem(deletedItem: ShoppingListElementItem, shoppingListId: Int) {
    dataSource.getShoppingList(shoppingListId)
            .firstElement()
            .subscribe {
                shoppingList: ShoppingList ->
                val items: ArrayList<ShoppingListItem> = shoppingList.items

                val filter = items.filter {
                    it.timestamp != deletedItem.timestamp
                }

                dataSource.updateShoppingList(shoppingList = ShoppingList(id = shoppingList.id,
                        name = shoppingList.name,
                        isArchived = shoppingList.isArchived,
                        timestamp = shoppingList.timestamp,
                        items = filter as ArrayList<ShoppingListItem>
                        ))
            }
}

fun restoreShoppingListItem(deletedItem: ShoppingListElementItem, shoppingListId: Int) {
    dataSource.getShoppingList(shoppingListId)
            .firstElement()
            .subscribe {
                shoppingList: ShoppingList ->
                val items = shoppingList.items
                items.add(ShoppingListItem(deletedItem.name, deletedItem.isCompleted, deletedItem.timestamp))
                dataSource.updateShoppingList(shoppingList = ShoppingList(id = shoppingList.id,
                        name = shoppingList.name,
                        isArchived = shoppingList.isArchived,
                        timestamp = shoppingList.timestamp,
                        items = items
                ))
            }
}

fun updateShoppingList(shoppingList: ArrayList<ShoppingListElementItem>, shoppingListId: Int) {
    dataSource.getShoppingList(shoppingListId)
            .firstElement()
            .subscribe {
                t: ShoppingList ->

                val dbShoppingList = ArrayList<ShoppingListItem>()
                shoppingList.forEach {
                    it -> dbShoppingList.add(ShoppingListItem(it.name, it.isCompleted, it.timestamp))
                }

                dataSource.updateShoppingList(shoppingList = ShoppingList(id = t.id,
                        name = t.name,
                        isArchived = t.isArchived,
                        timestamp = t.timestamp,
                        items = dbShoppingList
                ))
            }
}
}
```

Here is my Dao interface:

```
@Dao
interface ShoppingListDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM shopping_list where id = :id limit 1")
fun getShoppingList(id: Int): Flowable<ShoppingList>

@Query("SELECT * FROM shopping_list where not is_archived")
fun getActiveShoppingLists(): Flowable<List<ShoppingList>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM shopping_list where is_archived")
fun getArchivedShoppingLists(): Flowable<List<ShoppingList>>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertShoppingList(shoppingList: ShoppingList)

@Update
fun updateShoppingList(shoppingList: ShoppingList)

@Query("UPDATE shopping_list SET is_archived = 1 where id = :id")
fun archiveShoppingList(id: Int)

@Query("UPDATE shopping_list SET  is_archived = 0 where id = :id")
fun reArchiveShoppingList(id: Int)
}
```

And here is the Activity:

```
class ShoppingListDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecyclerItemTouchHelper.RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener, ShoppingItemCheckboxListener {

private lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
private lateinit var viewModel: ShoppingListViewModel
private var intExtra: Int? = null
private var isArchived: Boolean? = null
private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()
private var shoppingList = ArrayList<ShoppingListElementItem>()
private var mAdapter: ShoppingListDetailsAdapter? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    intExtra = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0)
    isArchived = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isArchived", false)

    viewModelFactory = Injection.provideViewModelFactory(this)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ShoppingListViewModel::class.java)

 //        mAdapter = ShoppingListDetailsAdapter(shoppingList, this, this, isArchived!!)

    val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager)
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(DefaultItemAnimator())
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
 //        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)

    if (isArchived as Boolean) {
        fab.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    else{
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            val alertDialogAndroid = getShoppingListDialog()
            alertDialogAndroid?.show()
        }
    }

    val itemTouchHelperCallback1 = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            // Row is swiped from recycler view
            // remove it from adapter
            if (viewHolder is ShoppingListDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder) {
                // get the removed item name to display it in snack bar
                val name = shoppingList[viewHolder.adapterPosition].name

                // backup of removed item for undo purpose
                val deletedItem = shoppingList[viewHolder.adapterPosition]
                val deletedIndex = viewHolder.adapterPosition

                // remove the item from recycler view
                mAdapter?.removeItem(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                viewModel.removeShoppingListItem(deletedItem, intExtra!!)


                // showing snack bar with Undo option
                val snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, name + " is deleted!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                snackbar.setAction("UNDO", View.OnClickListener {
                    // undo is selected, restore the deleted item
                    mAdapter?.restoreItem(deletedItem, deletedIndex)
                    viewModel.restoreShoppingListItem(deletedItem, intExtra!!)
                })
                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
                snackbar.show()
            }
            Log.v("Test", "test")
        }

        override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
        }
    }

    if (!isArchived!!)
        ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback1).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
}

fun getShoppingListDialog(): AlertDialog? {
    val layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    val mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.dialog_input_name, null)
    val alertDialogBuilderUserInput = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(mView)

    val userInputDialogEditText = mView.findViewById(R.id.userInputDialog) as EditText
    alertDialogBuilderUserInput
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Send", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogBox, id ->
                viewModel.createShoppingListItem(userInputDialogEditText.text.toString(), intExtra!!)
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogBox, id -> dialogBox.cancel() })

    return alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create()
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    onBackPressed()
    return true
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    if (intExtra != null)
        viewModel.getShoppingList(intExtra!!)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ t ->
                    shoppingList.clear()
                    t.items.forEach {
                        val item = ShoppingListElementItem(0, it.name, false, it.timestamp)
                        shoppingList.add(item)

                    }
                    shoppingList.size
                    mAdapter = ShoppingListDetailsAdapter(shoppingList, this, this, isArchived!!)
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)
//                        mAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                })
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()

    // clear all the subscription
    disposable.clear()
}

override fun onClick(position: Int, isChecked: Boolean) {
    shoppingList.get(position).isCompleted = isChecked
    viewModel.updateShoppingList(shoppingList, intExtra!!)
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "isChecked: ${isChecked}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int, position: Int) {
}

}
```

When i am trying to check the checbox in my RecyclerView item it immedietaly is checked to false then.

Here is the model entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "shopping_list")
data class ShoppingList(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_archived")
    val isArchived: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
    val timestamp: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "items")
    val items: ArrayList<ShoppingListItem>
)

data class ShoppingListItem(
    val name: String,
    val isCompleted: Boolean,
    val timestamp: Date
)
```

And the layout for shopping list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemName"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:text="GOWNO"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the ShoppingListElementItem class:

```
data class ShoppingListElementItem(
    var id: Int,
    var name: String,
    var isCompleted: Boolean,
    val timestamp: Date
)
```

The listener:

```
interface ShoppingItemCheckboxListener {

fun onClick(position: Int, isChecked: Boolean)
}
```

When i am trying to check the checkbox in my RecyclerView item, it immedietaly is checked back to false. In my Acitivty subscribe method after update the checkbox, the fetched updated item from db is correctly set to checked("isCompleted"), but i guess something wrong in my adapter setup. In my onBindViewHolder method the item, which was set to checked is always false, so i guess it is not updated properly the adapter list items.

How to make it work properly?

**UPDATE**

Even when i restart the app, the checkbox is not set to true, however the fetched item from db has the attribute "isCompleted" set to true. The problem is in the adapter really, i have no idea why it has no the items as i expect - in my subscribe method in Activity where i am fetching the items to be populated to the adapter they are correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could u pls check this function

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    if (intExtra != null)
        viewModel.getShoppingList(intExtra!!)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ t ->
                    shoppingList.clear()
                    t.items.forEach {
                        val item = ShoppingListElementItem(0, it.name, false, it.timestamp)
                        shoppingList.add(item)

                    }
                    shoppingList.size
                    mAdapter = ShoppingListDetailsAdapter(shoppingList, this, this, isArchived!!)
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)
//                        mAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                })
```

In this function you are subscribing for shopping list which is flowable, which means whenever there is an update in database this subscribe method will get called and  the following code will reset the completed value to false

```
ShoppingListElementItem(0, it.name, false, it.timestamp)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I forgot to set it properly like: ShoppingListElementItem(it.id, it.name, it.isCompleted, it.timestamp)

Comment: Actually, i removed the 'id' property, it is unnesseceary. Anyways, thanks again

Comment: Awesome. @okset

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this block of code

```
 holder?.isCompleted?.setOnCheckedChangeListener{
    buttonView, isChecked ->
    item.isCompleted = isChecked
    listener.onClick(position, isChecked)
}
```

When you click the checkbox, `isChecked` is true and if I am not mistaken, the `listener.onClick(position,isChecked)` clicks the same item in the `RecyclerView`. What does `ShoppingItemCheckboxListener` do?

Comment: Hi, i updated the question. I provided this listener to be able communicate to the hosting Activity that the checkbox in RecyclerView item was checked, so i can update my item in the ViewModel